# An error "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."

Tags: client-object-model

Below is the code and I am getting error in `context.ExecuteQuery();`

using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(url))
            {

```
            NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, pass,domain);
            clientContext.Credentials = credentials;
            Web web = clientContext.Web;

            clientContext.Load(web);

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            label1.Text = web.Title;
        }
```

Comment: Please add a little more information like which environment and explain the context.

Answer (score 0):

Since you error message says `Remote` server. I am assuming this is SharePoint online. If that is the case then you need to pass the Credentials to the clientcontext as below

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(url))
{
    SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in "yourpassword".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
    clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("yourlogin@yoursite.onmicrosoft.com", passWord);
    Web web = clientContext.Web;
    clientContext.Load(web);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    label1.Text = web.Title;
}
```

Comment: Its not sharepoint online. Just an simple code to get a site title. And i am not using Office365

Comment: @Anamika then add more details to your question